# Get the input on the same line java

Tags: java, input

I have this to ask the user a command but I want the input to be written on the same line the user is asked.

```
public class Controller{

private Scanner in;

   public void run(){


    String line;


    System.out.print("Command > ");
    line = in.next();


}
```

So I get this:

```
Command > 
help
```

And I want this:

```
Command > help
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: What terminal are you using? This should work fine.

Comment: Running on IntelliJ IDEA CE for Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE is lying to you a bit.  The current context that you have written will prompt on the same line when you run the .jar, but IntelliJ breaks the input and output between 2 different lines.  Rest assured that your prompt is working properly.